# How do I find latex source-code?

Tags: latex

Does anyone know where I could find the code that LaTeX uses to typeset inside the tabular environment? In the past I have looked in style files but I don't know where to find intrinsic LaTeX commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [PDF file of the LaTeX sources](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf), chapter `lttab.dtx`.

Comment: Or indeed just read latex.ltx (inside <texmf>/tex/latex/base).